# SQL - Ordering by a number which recycles when it reaches 999

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to order by a number which recycles when it reaches 999. The number range runs 1 - 999 and it should always run in ascending order. Currently my SQL (`ORDER BY BoxID ASC, Seqno ASC`) is generating the following result:

[image: example of sequence range incorrectly ordered]

The box number will always increment by 1 every 9 sequence numbers. so in the example shown in the box 35897 the range should run 999, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8

There are no time stamps which can be used to find the order as the sequential numbers are inserted into the database in a random order.

Comment: Look again - the order in your image corresponds EXACTLY to your order by clause. The claimed out-of-order 999 has Box 35897 while the next row is Box 35898. If you expect that to be first - well, that's impossible.

Comment: Can you also share the expected result for this data? It would make the question much clearer

Comment: To expand on this, you need some sort of "series" indicator that can be used to determine that a given value of 999 is series "x" which precedes anything from series "y". And you indicated you have nothing else. So - impossible.

Comment: This sounds like a strange take on an islands-and-gaps problem. You want 999 to have no gap with 1, and you want to start with the lowest number after a gap. I think it MIGHT be possible, but I think it's going to be not very efficient or easy. You'd have to come up with code that sees the gap between 8 and 999, but no gap between 999 and 1 (treating 999 as zero in this case... 998 as negative one, etc) and that will be very difficult I think.

Comment: Good question. Next time please show your data as text, not as an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem only occurs when there is both 1 and 999 in a box's sequence numbers. There are never more than nine rows per box in the table. So detect the case and add 1000 to the low numbers.

```
select *
from mytable
order by
  box, 
  case when min(number) over (partition by box) = 1
        and max(number) over (partition by box) = 999
        and number < 500
       then number + 1000
       else number
  end;
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f775b15e01ff6b88a86028dd59e3eb86

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of a stab in the dark, but perhaps...

```
SELECT Box,
       Number
FROM YourTable
ORDER BY Box,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Number ORDER BY Box ASC),
         Number;
```

This, however, won't work if a single box has over 999 values for `Number`.

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ca69398c07185d81622ff4585da7de91) showing solution (As DB Fiddle  limits the result set to 10 rows, I have had to use a CTE to show relevant rows).

Comment: This is a nice way to solve this. The 999 occurs for the first time, while the 1 occurs for the second time, so you get the 999 before the 1. Good thinking.

Comment: I don't seem to be able to get this solution to give the expected result consistently, if I take off the number in the Order By this works for the first occurrence of the 999 and 1 in a box but not on the second occurrence then it works for the third occurrence in the results, etc.

Comment: Do you have more than 999 numbers for a single box? As noted, this won't work if that is the case. Without proper sample data, I can't give you an answer, as it clearly works for the data demonstrated.